# Should we always use clustered standard errors in panel data with only two time points, in a multilevel logistic regression?

Tags: logistic, mixed-model, panel-data, autocorrelation, clustered-standard-errors

This is the situation:

1. I have a binary outcome at two timepoints (T1 and T2);
2. I'm using a random-effect logistic regression (I mean: just the random intercept, no random slopes) to estimate subject-specific effects.

My question is: **should I use cluster-robust standard errors?** Since the time points are just two, here there is no risk of wrong specification of the autocorrelation structure (I mean: there's no difference between "unstrctured", "AR1" and "exchangeble"), as long as we are confident that there is residual correlation between the observations of the same person (otherwise, the random intercept should be removed). So, **the only reason I see to include cluster-robust standard errors is: to take into account the error in estimating the autocorrelation parameter. Am I right? In case: is it something advisable even when the number of clusters is relatively large (hundreds of people)?**

I can add some other features of my situation, in case they were relevant: my panel is strongly unbalanced (T2 observations are available only for $43.5\%$ of observations); I'm controlling for outcome values at baseline (T0) and including "time" both as a predictor and in interaction terms, so that the effect of each covariate is allowed to differ between timepoints; finally, all covariates are constant across time.

Comment: Can you specify what you mean by cluster-robust standard errors?

Comment: I mean that the standard errors allow for intragroup correlation, so that the two within-subject errors are not independent.

Comment: With only 2 periods, AR1 doesn't make sense to me . It would make more sense with 3 or more. Pesaran's test for cross-sectional dependence may be useful...here https://docs.iza.org/dp1240.pdf  or here https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0600600403

Answer (score 0):

If you've controlled for autocorrelation using AR(1), there's no need to account for it a second time using cluster-robust errors. Make sure you actually have controlled for the autocorrelation and are getting the right SE, though; assuming the within-subject observations have already been adjusted away will get the wrong answer, and that's a pretty easy mistake to make if you're not careful with your code.

If you have a large sample, bootstrapping the clusters themselves is a pretty easy way to get a good standard error without having to triple-check that your code is actually doing what you think it is, or you can check the bootstrapped errors closely match what your software is putting out.

Comment: Thank you. With just two timepoints, just one random-effect parameter has to be estimated: what can go wrong? The output gives me its variance (with its standard error and confidence intervals), together with the p-value of the likelihood-ratio test (on the boundary) against the one-level logistic model.